# PHP Associative Arrays: Storing Keys and values

Tags: php, associative-array

I am pretty new with associative arrays.  Just trying to create a dynamic associative array.

Current Array -

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [354] => Array
        (
        )

    [355] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Trying to get desired output

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [354] => Array
        (
            [activity_desc] = "description"
        )

    [355] => Array
        (
           [activity_desc] = "description"
        )

)
```

wrote an sql to check key (354, 355) and return description.

How to I store key and value under 344 & 355?

Current code:

```html
foreach ($report as $key=>$value) 
{
    $where = 'item_id = ' . $key . '';  
 $query = $db->prepare('SELECT activity_desc FROM program WHERE '. $where);
 $query->execute();
 $test = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

this is my sql return query for 354.  355 will be roughly the same.

```html
stdClass Object ( [activity_desc] => <p>Send Activity</p>
```

Thanks in advance

Fugz

Answer (score 1):

wow it was that simple........

$report->$key = $test;